# How can I differentiate a plus operator from a positive sign in Lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I am writing lex for a language almost like C and I need to differentiate these two signs. For example:

`a+b` -> plus sign

`+a` -> positive sign

Where `a` and `b` can be numbers or identifiers. I already have regex for numbers and identifiers but now I'm stuck in this question. How can I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the lexer's job to distinguish between infix and prefix operators. A plus sign should produce the same token either way and then the parser can treat it differently depending on whether it occurs in prefix or infix position.

Comment: So can I just return the sign from the lexer or is there a better way?

Comment: @asdas Right, you'd just return `+` from the lexer and then the parser would have separate rules for `'+' expression` and `expression '+' expression`.